# Pivot MySQL table setting boolean values

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have to perform what I think is a very basic MYSQL table pivot, but I am completely new to sql so I am not sure about the syntax. I have the following table

```
record_id tag_id
id_1      tag1
id_1      tag2
id_2      tag1
id_2      tag3
```

I would like to obtain a pivoted table, whose rows are the unique record_ids, the columns are the unique tag_ids, and the values are boolean true/false if that record_id has that tag. In this case, the expected result would be:

```
record_id tag1  tag2  tag3
id_1      true  true  false
id_2      true  false true
```

How can I achieve this?

Further question: what if I have another table that associates tag_names to tag_id, and I would like the columns of my pivoted table to be named after tag_names? In this example, starting from

```
tag_id tag_name
tag1   tag_name1
tag2   tag_name2
tag3   tag_name3
```

I would finally get

```
record_id tag_name1  tag_name2  tag_name3
id_1      true       true       false
id_2      true       false      true
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If taglist is static and will be altered never then you may use a bunch of CASEs. If not then stored procedure only.

Comment: @Akina taglist is indeed static but it has 18 tags, so I didn't really want to write everything explicitly. I will follow your advice if you think it is the best way. How would you write the query in this 3 tags example?

Comment: Changed [tag:pivot] to [tag:pivot-table]. The former tag is for the Microsoft SQL Server `PIVOT` syntax, but MySQL doesn't support that extension to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT record_id,
       CASE WHEN SUM(tag_id = 'tag1') THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END tag1,
       CASE WHEN SUM(tag_id = 'tag2') THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END tag2,
       CASE WHEN SUM(tag_id = 'tag3') THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END tag3
FROM source_table
GROUP BY record_id
ORDER BY record_id
```